# Clustering 3D data with one nominal scale

Tags: python, algorithm, 3d, cluster-analysis, pattern-recognition

**Problem Statement**

I have 2D pandas dataframes that hold data about user tool usage characteristics (e.g. 88% usage of System A, 11% usage of system B, 1% system C for a respective user:

```
        A      B       C
Usage  0,88   0,11   0,01
```

Assume that three users (ID: 1, 2, 3) are present the following matrices are present:

```
ID:1    A      B       C     ID:2    A      B      C     ID:3    A      B    C
Usage  0,88   0,11   0,01    Usage  0,86   0,13   0,01   Usage  0,00  0,00  1,00
```

I thought of aggregating the single 2D matrices to a 3D matrix to identify clusters of similar usage behaviour.

**Goal**

Identify clusters within system usage. In this example ID1 and ID2 should be clustered. I build a working [DBSCAN method](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#dbscan) for clustering random 2D data.

However, I Face the problem of having the 2D matrices stacked in a fixed sequence within the aggregated 3D matrix. Thereby it is not possible to identify similarity while only looking at one fixed nominal sequence, because basically every user 2D data must be compared to all other 2D data to find smiliar usage behaviour.

**Thoughts**

I thought of integrating a method somewhat k-fold crossvalidation method for small data sets in machine learning. However I don't know how to integrate such a behavior into a clustering algorithm.

Another thought is that maybe pattern recognition or hierarchical clustering (although total number of clusters is unknown)
 is the better way to go as the third axis of the aggregated 3D matrix is on nominal scale (user ID). However, I am unexperienced within the domain of patter recognition up to this point.

Maybe someone has a good methodic idea to solve this clustering problem. :)

Comment: Can you just do the clustering on features A,B, and C without taking user ID into account? In your example you have 3 users each having a position in 3 dimensions on the same scale, this seems perfect input for clustering.

Comment: @Pallie I could do that but I must be able to tell which users are close to each other and belong to the same "usage cluster". Do you have an idea how to accomplish that?

Comment: Usage cluster is what you're trying to predict, right? Just plug the data into any clustering algorithm and see which works well for the desired result.

Comment: Yeah that's right! I want to use DBSCAN therefor. At the moment I'm trying to figure out how to plug in my matrix into the DBSCAN example. But I'm not able to figure out how to input the ```labels_true``` variable from the referenced DBSCAN example. Maybe you have an idea, because I have no data for it. It is describing the ground truth class assignments, which are obviously unknown. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example uses `labels_true` only for evaluation, not as input for the DBSCAN itself. The `labels_true` are derived from the function that creates the mock dataset. The correct  way to call dbscan is `db = DBSCAN(eps=0.3, min_samples=10).fit(X)` Where x in your case is `[[valueA, valueB, valueC], [valueA, valueB, valueC], ...]` The result is then in `db.labels_`.